# Error when combining two arrays in a datatable in Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, datatable, google-visualization

The same Value (PIB) is repeating in every row when it should assign **one Value to one Date**. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

I have this 2 arrays from a JSON url:

```
    var date = [array1];
    var number = [array2];
```

I create the Table and add two columns:

```
    var figure = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    figure.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    figure.addColumn('number', 'PIB');
```

And I am sure here is **the problem**, I create loops to parse both arrays and try to combine them with figure.addRow:

```
  for (j in num){
      var myVal = parseFloat(number[j]); 
  };
  
  for (i in date){
      var dated = new Date(date[i]);
      figure.addRow([dated, myVal]);
  };
```

Full code in my fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/Enrique_94/khrg0ume/3/  )

Thank you!

Comment: Your two `for` loops should be nested.

Comment: @DavidTansey i have tried one loop inside the other and it returns me the same error with another number

Comment: I assume the 2 arrays are the same length - in which case, as you iterate through the date array, use the same index value `i` to also access the equivalent element in the number array. One loop, but using that one index in both arrays.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with just one loop and same index

```js
    for (i in num){
        var myVal = parseFloat(num[i]); 
        var dated = new Date(date[i]);
        figure.addRow([dated, myVal]);
        };
```